# Keras model not resuming training well

Tags: machine-learning, python, keras

I tried resuming training with my keras model, to save the model I used `model.save('model.h5')`. And to load it again I used `model = load_model('model.h5')`. I am using batch gradient descent i.e. the training data for each epoch is just one large batch. However, when I resume my training the error rate goes upto 100x then comes back down to about 2x, when compared to where the model left off, and this happens every time i resume training. Why is this so? And what is the solution?

Comment: Are you chnaging the data for the model while resuming the training?

Comment: No, the data is the same @ShubhamPanchal